# A simple mod re-write rule doesnt work with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want the user to be redirected whenever he reaches my subdomain

Here is what is inside my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^http://smale.deals.com/(.*) http://traual.deals.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^http://deals.com/smale/(.*) http://deals.com/traual/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But no redirect happens. why?

I also have got this in my root htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Android|iPhone|iPod|Blackberry) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ mobile/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot include the protocol and domain in `RewriteRule`. Those need to be accounted for in `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite requests to smale.deals.com to traual.deals.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^smale\.deals\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://traual.deals.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# For deals.com...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^deals\.com$ [NC]
# Rewrite requests to smale/ to deals.com/traual/
RewriteRule ^smale/(.*) http://deals.com/traual/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: dammit, the code seems to be right, but it has no effect.. may be because my htaccess is inside a folder..and it is requested like this:'http://smale.deals.com/'

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd If the two hosts `deals.com` and `smale.deals.com` do not share the same document root, you will need to put the .htaccess relevant parts in the doc root of each.

Comment: They do share the same root. But smale is a folder inside deals

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Just realized I had `%` instead of `$` at the ends of both the `RewriteCond` domain patterns.  Change those as I have above.

Comment: That is my folder structure: deals.com/smale... i try to redirect to deals.com/traual/.. see also my answer update

Comment: and you have placed the .htaccess at the doc root `deals.com/`?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Move it up into the document root so it applies to everything below